# PostgreSQL PostGIS: get geography lines interceptions

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to solve one problem with PostGIS module in PostgreSQL 15 server.

Incoming Data:

1. Geographic Coordinates of Point 1. (X1,Y1)
2. Geographic Coordinates of Point 2. (X2,Y2).
3. Bearing angle from point 1 (alpha).
4. Bearing angle from point 2 (beta).

Is it possible to make a "geographical" lines (using SRID EPSG:4326) , using incoming data
and get an interception of this lines?

I was trying to make this using geometry object and rotate vertical line on bearing angle. After that I get an interception. But it seems that it is not a right solution for real geographical coordinates.

[image]

Does anybody have some ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Affine transformations in PostGIS are planar operations only. You are trying to solve geodetic problems, of which e.g. [*Vincenty's* algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) are baked into `ST_Distance` and `ST_Project` - the latter of which is your best bet:

```
SELECT
  ST_Intersection(
    ST_MakeLine(
      <point_1>,
      ST_Project(
        <point_1>::GEOGRAPHY,
        <proxy_distance_in_meter>,
        <alpha_bearing_in_rad>
      )::GEOMETRY
    )::GEOGRAPHY,
    ST_MakeLine(
      <point_2>,
      ST_Project(
        <point_2>::GEOGRAPHY,
        <proxy_distance_in_meter>,
        <beta_bearing_in_rad>
      )::GEOMETRY
    )::GEOGRAPHY
;
```

*Note the series of type casts necessary to apply spheroidal arithmetics.*

Here you will have to add a `<proxy_distance_in_meter>` based on educated guesses (or e.g. quarter/third average circumference of Earth), as there is no built-in way to solve for finding the intersection distance.

You could write your own function, wrapping the much easier spherical (great circle) algebra to do this in one call, though.